# Update two columns with list of data in sql server SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have one table that have Ads_Id And Priority in sql server

it possible the create procedure for update Ads_Id And Priority with a list ?

for example in a single query

```
update AdsPriority set [Priority] = 3 where Ads_Id = 1
```

change to

```
update AdsPriority set [Priority] = (List Of Id) where Ads_Id = (List of Priority)
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not the way you've described it.
You can use joins in an update statement, so I would go with something like this:

```
DECLARE @Priority AS TABLE (priority int, id int)

INSERT INTO @Priority VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) .... (n,n)

UPDATE t
SET t.[Priority] = p.[Priority]
FROM AdsPriority t
INNER JOIN @Priority p ON(t.Ads_Id = p.id)
```

Since it's a stored procedure, you can use a table valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE udtTuple As TABLE (int1 int, int2 int)
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE stpUpdateAbsPriority
(
   @Priority dbo.udtTuple readonly
)
AS

UPDATE t
SET t.[Priority] = p.[int1]
FROM AdsPriority t
INNER JOIN @Priority p ON(t.Ads_Id = p.int2)

GO
```

Comment: Pleled, thank you for your answer, can you convert this to the stored procedure ?

Comment: @kalim did you see the second part of the answer? it's already a stored procedure....